# Error Calling Calendar API: Principal must be an email address

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

We wrote a software more than 1 year ago to sync events from google calendars. It's been working since March 2018, but it suddendly stop working this months on every Gsuite instances we use for us and for our customers.

The problem is that we are using a service account to access calendar resources events via google CalendarAPI v3.
After authenticating with service account credentials , for every service call we now encounter the error:

> "Error:\"invalid_request\", Description:\"Principal must be an email address\", Uri:\"\""

I cannot find an answer anywhere about this problem, it sounds like a policy change on Google service, but I cannot be sure about this.
It seems like Google API is complaining about service account email, that isn't actually a real valid email. It is in this format:

mydomain.com_(client_id)313.......@resource.calendar.google.com

Do you think the problem could be related to the service account email address?
And why it was working before April and now stop working?

One possible solution, not yet tried:

I sow it is possible to use "delegation" for the service acount.
What would happens if I try to use a valid user email and delegate it upon my service account?

```
/* function I use to authenticate my service account to Google Calendar
* service. serviceAccount is the email (Principal not working?) and json is 
* the key generated for him.
*/
public void bindCalendarService(string json, string serviceAccount)
    {
        var cr = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersonalServiceAccountCred>(json);
        ServiceAccountCredential xCred = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(cr.client_id, cr.token_uri)
        {
            Scopes = new string[] {
                CalendarService.Scope.Calendar,
            },
            User = serviceAccount
        }.FromPrivateKey(cr.private_key));

        CalendarService calendarService = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = xCred
        });
        this.calendarService = calendarService;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to give access to unsecured apps on google account security, 
try this : https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en
if it do not work talk to me.

Answer (score 0):

I solve today the problem in onother way.

1) I tried to implement delegation like it is wxplained on:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority
It works.

2) Without delegation, I changed my metod posted avove in this way:

var credentialParameters = NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Instance.Deserialize(json);

```
        ServiceAccountCredential xCred = new ServiceAccountCredential(
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(**credentialParameters.ClientEmail**)
            {
                Scopes = new string[] {
                    CalendarService.Scope.Calendar
                },
                User = serviceAccount,         // service account's email
            }.FromPrivateKey(credentialParameters.PrivateKey));
```

It works even in this way.
It is still a mistery why above code stopped working after 1 year.

Hope it will help someone
Thanks